# configuring AEM dispatcher 6.2 CSRF filters

Tags: configuration, adobe, aem, dispatcher

I am trying to follow the instruction on the adobe checklist, but there are no examples on how to configure this filter or test that it works. Looking for any insight and example of how this should work on the dispatcher.

[The dispatcher checklist](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/security-checklist.html#Configure%20Dispatcher%20to%20prevent%20CSRF%20Attacks)

```
 /0084
    {
    /type "allow"
    /path "/libs/granite/csrf/token.json"
    /extension '(json)'
    }
```

I assume this is correct but I have no way of verifying. also no idea how I can create a filter for:

> Creating a filter to allow the CSRF-Token header

Appreciate your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
/filter
{
...
    /0084 { /type "allow" /glob "GET /libs/granite/csrf/token.json*" }
}
```